# FXML parent element not injected in child controller

Tags: javafx-2, fxml, fxmlloader

I am trying to figure-out why parent element is always `null` in following JavaFX code. 
`MenuBar` is used as a child inside gl.fmxl (see above). `MenuBar` is using  controller called MenuController. Now when I hit `MenuController` by clicking on a menu then `@FXML protected VBox gl;` is always `null` in `GlController`

**here is how MenuBar component is created using menu_bar.fxml file below**

```
public class MenuBar extends FlowPane {

    public MenuBar(){
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fragments/top_menu.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        fxmlLoader.setController(new MenuController());
        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

***gl.fxml***

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import com.ui.layouts.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
            fx:controller="com.ui.controllers.GlController">

    <VBox fx:id="gl">
        <MenuBar fx:id="menuBar"></MenuBar>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

**top_menu.fxml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity"
          minWidth="-Infinity" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
   <children>
       <MenuBar >
           <menus>
               <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                   <items>
                       <MenuItem fx:id="createCsvFile" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#exportCsvData" text="GL" />
                   </items>
               </Menu>
               <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="CSV">
                   <items>
                       <MenuItem fx:id="openCsvFile" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processCsvData" text="open" />
                   </items>
               </Menu>
               <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Products">
                   <items>
                       <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showProducts" text="saving" />
                   </items>
               </Menu>
               <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Accounts">
                   <items>
                       <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#showAccountTransactions" text="show" />
                   </items>
               </Menu>
           </menus>
       </MenuBar>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

**Main.java**

Here is how I initialise the javaFX application

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
    Parent parentView  = fxmlLoader.load(getClass().getResource("ui/layouts/gl.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(parentView, 1200, 800));
    primaryStage.show();

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**MenuController.java**

```
public class MenuController {

    GlController glController = new GlController();

    @FXML protected void processCsvData(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

        MenuItem menuItem = (MenuItem)event.getSource();
        if (menuItem.getId().equals(openCsvFile.getId())) {
            File file = browseFile("CSV", "*.csv");
            String csvData = buildCsv(file.getPath()).toString();
            List<Transactionable> transactionList = glToCsv.buildTransactions(csvData, TransactionType.ACTUAL_TRANSACTION);
            addTableItem(transactionTableView, transactionList);
        }
    }

}
```

**GlController**

```
public class GlController {

    @FXML protected VBox gl;

    public Scene getScene(){
        return gl.getScene();
    }
}
```

I am hitting `processCsvData` by clicking on menu to debug the value of `glController.getScene()` which is always `null`

Comment: How do you check this? You never get any reference to the `GlController` class and you don't seem to use any event handlers or a `initialize` method...

Comment: @fabian I am testing by hitting menuController. When I debug glController.gl value is always null

Comment: I moved `GlController glController = new GlController();` inside the `MenuController` class, since this seems what you're doing instead of declaring it before the class, which would result in a compile time error, since it doesn't seem to be a inner class of `MenuBar`.